# Keep permalinks when migrate blog

Tags: web-scraping, b2evolution

I'm planning to migrate my blog from [b2evolution](http://b2evolution.net/) to Something Completely Different (to be determined). It's unlikely that I'll use an automated import or conversion utility.

I want to extract all the Permalink URLs and associate them with the post titles, in order to make it easier to create a redirect file.

My old blog will be inaccessible after the conversion, so I won't be able to refer to it.

Is there an easy way to do this? (I could write something by hand with HTMLAgilityPack, but that would take hours.)

Alternately, is there a quick way to create an offline copy of the (dynamic PHP) site with the URLs preserved?

Comment: `Alternately, is there a quick way to create an offline copy of the (dynamic PHP) site with the URLs preserved?` > If I'm not mistaken, something like winHTTrack can "grab" your whole existing site and save an offline version of it using the same directory structure (was it a fake "URL-rewrited" one). You could then host those static pages (and images and so) on your new dynamic site, as archives (no new comment and so => you may need some updates on page layout too to remove "add comment" and so)

Comment: @Bartdude I tried Offline Downloader but it screwed up the pages and the URLs big-time. If there's a specific program that will work, that would be an acceptable answer. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I've used [WinHTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) several times along the years and each time with a good result. The interface is ugly and not very user-friendly, but it gets the job done and is free. I think it's worth giving it a try.

Comment: @Bartdude - that worked. The permalinks need some slight massaging (strip prefix and trailing .html, add http colon slashes) but that's not an issue. If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [WinHTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) to save an offline version of the site as per @Bartdude's suggestion. The permalinks need some slight massaging (strip prefix and trailing .html, add http colon slashes) but that's not an issue. Similar tools might also work.